# No DisplayPort/HDMI Audio options in sound settings.

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, displayport

i know that there is many articles on this very issue, and i have scoured everyone i could get my hands on with no luck.

i have an Optiplex 780, with an Intel Q45/43 chip set that has a display port out option. i use an DP to HDMI adapter, which works fine with video to my TV. However, i have no sound, and the only adapter listed is the built in analog audio. i am running 16.04 and i would appreciate any help i could get on this, i have reached a wall. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Intel Forums thread](https://communities.intel.com/thread/67442), your Q45/43 chipset does support audio through DisplayPort, so that isn't the problem.

The marked solution says something rather important I think:

> The problem stems from the fact that I have a Passive DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter with an older onboard DisplayPort. What I needed to include audio and video was an Active DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter.

Since you haven't specified (and I don't blame you for not thinking about this), I have to assume that you have a passive adapter. You should get ahold of an active version.

Something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-DisplayPort-Supporting-Technology/dp/B00EDT0072](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EDT0072)